# scanner InputMismatchException issue with while loop

Tags: java, exception, while-loop

```
    (bank is a static int variable declared up top)
    boolean valid = true;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    while (valid) {
        try {
        System.out.println("How much money do you want to convert to chips?");
        bank = scan.nextInt();
        valid = false;
        } catch(InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Thats not right try entering a number between 0 and 2,147,483,647");
            //bank = scan.nextInt();
            continue;
        } 

    }
```

If i uncomment the second bank = scan.nextInt(); i get the same InputMismatchError, but i dont have another try catch so it prints out stacktrace. 
How can i change this loop to accept a new input at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
static int bank = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean valid = true;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("How much money do you want to convert to chips?");
        if(scan.hasNextInt()){
            bank = scan.nextInt();
            valid = true;
        }else{
            scan.nextLine();
            valid = false;
            System.out.println("Enter a valid integer value");
        }
    }while(!valid);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You've probably entered a non-integer character(s) so that needs to be consumed

```
} catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input: " + scan.nextLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another try/catch in catch block but I believe that is not what you would like to do. If you really want to do this nice you should read about state machine pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern#Java. In that approach you can scan input in loop but depending on state, react differently.